# Problem with disabling JavaScript minifier in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay, minify, portal

I have a problem with disabling JavaScript minifier in Liferay 5.2.3.
I tried the following things:

- put property javascript.fast.load=false to portal-ext.properties
- put property com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter=false to portal-ext.properties
- set js_fast_load url parameter to 0

but it still works. What could I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I've found the solution.

When I disabled StripFilter, the content has not been minimized.

portal-ext.properties:
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter=false

It's strange, because I didn't find any documentation about such a behaviour of this filter. I discovered it after an analysis of the Liferay source code.

Dear readers, any comment about the StripFilter is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The minifierfilter was not working when i only disabled it, but the problem was that all my javascripts were not loading.  Disabling the strip filter and turning of the fast load fixed it.  It's also worth mentioning that you can delete the minifier files on the filesystem when you disable the filter.

Answer (score 4):

To disable the minifier without modifying the portal properties add the following parameters to your url query string:

`js_fast_load=0 <-- disable js minifier`

css_fast_load=0 **<-- disable css minifier**

strip=0 **<-- disable strip filter**

See http://www.liferay.com/web/igor.spasic/blog/-/blogs/turn-off-minifiers-and-html-stripping

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your portal-ext.properties is loaded by the portal? It should print the location during startup.

One way to make absolutely sure minifier is not used you can comment out the filter from web.xml.

Comment: When portal starts up I have a following log fragment:

Loading file:/C:/programs/liferay-portal-5.2.3/portal-ext.properties

and in portal-ext.properties I have the following properties set:

javascript.fast.load=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter=false

Moreover, I edited \webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml and commented all minifier filters and JavaScript code in my portlet is still minimized.

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Minimification and whitespace stripping is two different things. MinifierFilter will try to minimize the javascript without breaking it. StripFilter will just get rid of extra whitespace. During development you might want to enable the portal-developer.properties which turns off caching, minimification and stripping. You can do that by adding JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dexternal.properties=portal-developer.properties" in you setenv.sh or setenv.bat of your tomcat depending on your os.